# How to upload videos on Youtube using AWS S3 as Video Source

Tags: amazon-s3, youtube-api

I have a VIDEO CMS hosted over AWS EC2 where user can upload videos and later share on Facebook and Youtube. I push videos to S3 after uploading and delete it from EC2.

Now I want to use S3 to share videos to both social networks. However FB provides a way to upload videos directly from S3 but Youtubes need video to be physically present on server.

I have not found any solution yet.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If it is not compulsory your video should be shared on youtube from amazon S3, you can directly upload your video to youtube by using youtube api, either javascript or other backend you are using. It will be much easier way. S3 doesnot provide any way to upload your video on youtube.
 Also you will have to manually check for new videos added to s3 and need to manually upload to youtube.

You will have to upload video on youtbe just after user/ you uploads on EC2. It will be dynamic.

You can get Youtube vidoe insert api resource from here 
 https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert

Comment: We are already doing that. But the main problem is, some of the videos are larger which blocks EC2 resources. So we want to make the process serverless. Also our raw video repo is S3. That's why we are trying to specify S3 path into youtube's API.

Comment: Configure your EC2 for that . Increase your upload size limit in httpd Apache configuration. It will be easily done.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, But everything is already in place and working fine for last 2 years. But now we are willing to move to serverless platform. That's why, An alternate solution is needed.

Comment: @nikhilkhare did you find a way?